# use multiple parenthesis in mysql where clause

Tags: mysql

Here's what I'm wanting to do in a "DELETE" statement:

```
delete from table1 
where (username = "Jonathan" or username = "Amy") 
and (field2 = "Jonathan" or field3 = "Jonathan" or field4 = "Jonathan" or field2 = "Amy" or field 3 = "Amy" or field4 = "Amy")
```

Surely there's a way to do this right?

EDIT:
Here's the actual code I'm using. I must be doing something wrong:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM friend_requests
    WHERE username in ('jesusfreak', " . $_SESSION['user']['username'] . ")
    AND (requests in ('jesusfreak', " . $_SESSION['user']['username'] . ")
    OR common_friends in ('jesusfreak', " . $_SESSION['user']['username'] . ")
    OR suggest_favorited in ('jesusfreak', " . $_SESSION['user']['username'] . ")
    OR suggest_prayed ('jesusfreak', " . $_SESSION['user']['username'] . ")
    OR suggest_viewed in ('jesusfreak', " . $_SESSION['user']['username'] . "))";

    $conn = new mysqli(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$conn->query($sql);
$conn->close();
```

Comment: What is wrong with you quoted example? Barring explaining how it's result might differ from your logic/expectation, which you have not disclosed, that is a legitimate `DELETE` statement. (Hint: You can change `DELETE FROM` to `SELECT * FROM` to preview what would be deleted.)

Comment: Good to know that it is legitimate. It simply isn't deleting anything. :-/ Good idea on using select to preview. I'll try that and reply

Comment: When I use "select *" I get an error message:  Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

Comment: That sounds like an error in whatever code you are using to run the query, not an issue with the query itself. You'll probably need to add code, or a reasonable approximation, to your question.

Comment: try to set up an echo $sql before the $conn->query($sql); to see the actual query that is executing.

Comment: good idea. I'm getting this: DELETE FROM friend_requests WHERE username in (jesusfreak, jonathan) AND (requests in (jesusfreak, jonathan) OR common_friends in (jesusfreak, jonathan) OR suggest_favorited in (jesusfreak, jonathan) OR suggest_prayed (jesusfreak, jonathan) OR suggest_viewed in (jesusfreak, jonathan))

Comment: When I try to run the statement manually in SQL I get the error: #1305 - FUNCTION wiseman_prayerpond.suggest_prayed does not exist

Comment: Okay, here's the answer. In order for it to work I have to put "" around the value.

To do that I made $user = "'" . $user . "'"; $username = "'" . $user . "'";

Comment: You could've used single quotes as well; and regarding your second most recent comment, you are missing an `IN`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
 delete from table1 
 where username in ('Jonathan','Amy')
         and (field2 in ('Jonathan','Amy') 
                or 
               field3 in ('Jonathan','Amy')
                or 
              field4 in ('Jonathan','Amy'));
```